# factory_boy one to many relationship

Tags: python, factory-boy

I have an one-to-many relationship and want to create a factory for it but don't know how to do this with factory_boy API.
One-to-one relationships are easy, just use `SubFactory`, but how to do this for a one-to-many relationship?

Example:

```
class Order(object):
    def __init__(self, id, itens):
        self.id = id
        self.itens = itens

class Item(object):
    def __init__(self, id, itens):
        self.id = id


class OrderFactory(SQLAlchemyModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Order

    id = lazy_attribute(lambda o: random.randint(1, 1000))
    itens = ????
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use post generation hook:

```
@factory.post_generation
def items(self, create, extracted, **kwargs):
    if not create:
        return

    if extracted:
        for item in extracted:
            self.items.add(item)
```